# AWS ELB not able to establish connection to Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

For the last two years, I haven't had a single problem with my Rails application handling requests; however, about two weeks ago, I've started noticing a significant increase of HTTP 504 Gateway Time-out being returned by AWS ELB.

From my investigation, I have noticed that that client receives the HTTP 504 exactly 10 seconds after the GET request. In other cases, the GET request retrieves its response in less than 2 seconds usually.

When looking at the logs in Amazon Athena, I can see the -1 in the "request_processing_time", "target_processing_time", and "response_processing_time"

[image]

I am running a Ruby on Rails application that sits behind ELB. I have tried inspecting the traffic to match the GET request being passed by ELB, but I don't see any mention of the URI in the `logs/production.log`

I understand that the AWS documentation states the following for `request_processing_time`:

- This value is set to -1 if the load balancer can't dispatch the request to a target. This can happen if the target closes the connection before the idle timeout or if the client sends a malformed request.
- This value can also be set to -1 if the registered target does not respond before the idle timeout.

However, wouldn't I be able to see this request in the Rails `log/production.log` file? It seems like the ELB is claiming connection issues to the target even though the target (the Rails app) doesn't have anything mentioned in the `log/production.log` file for the responses it's claiming are taking too long. I'm able to see the other requests.

There has been a small increase of traffic over the last few months, but I can't see how it would nearly result in 250+ HTTP 504 error messages every hour compared to literally none two weeks ago, so it's mind-boggling.

Does this have anything to do with the Rails puma server that's running? Using Rails 6.1.4.4 and puma 5.6.4

Comment: you would not be able to see the requests in the production.log because the ELB could not contact the app.  It could be that a) the app has hit some threshold in processing requests, b) you are getting by script kiddies sending crappy requests that the ELB is bouncing.  Might want see if adding another instance of the app helps, also check out the memory usage, etc on the existing instance.

Comment: Hey @dbugger thanks for your response. I actually just concluded the exact same thing. Too many requests at the same time, even though the requests are very short in turnaround time. Will need to get this moved. Really appreciate this input.

Comment: we run 2-8 web containers on 2-3 underlying EC2 instances for our apps and has worked out well for responsiveness